# Tomar resultados de una consulta sql server y usarlos en otra consulta

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, sql-server-2008

Quisiera hacer que los datos arrojados por una consulta se guarden en una variable para luego usarlos en un `delete`

Ejemplo:

```
select CodigoArticulo, CantidadEntrega 
       from TraspasosMercanciaSucursales 
       where FechaCreacion between '2019-08-17 00:00:00.000' and '2019-08-17 23:59:59.000' 
             and CodigoSucursal ='A'
```

Lo intente con `INNER JOIN` pero no me funciono del todo.

Comment: El problema seguramente es tu sentencia de `DELETE`, por que no agregas el código de la misma, ya que es totalmente factible resolverlo de esta forma.

Comment: Perdon creo que no me explique del todo, no se me ocurre como meterlos en una sentencia delete

Muchas gracias por contestar tan rapido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer directamente un `DELETE` a partir de tu consulta, mediante un `INNER JOIN`:

```
DELETE  tabla_donde_eliminar
        FROM tabla_donde_eliminar T
        INNER JOIN (select DISTINCT CodigoArticulo 
                           from TraspasosMercanciaSucursales 
                           where FechaCreacion between '2019-08-17 00:00:00.000' and '2019-08-17 23:59:59.000' 
                           and CodigoSucursal ='A'
       ) B
       ON B.CodigoArticulo = T.CodigoArticulo
```

O bien, usando la clausula `IN`

```
DELETE  tabla_donde_eliminar
        WHERE CodigoArticulo IN (
                        select DISTINCT CodigoArticulo 
                               from TraspasosMercanciaSucursales 
                               where FechaCreacion between '2019-08-17 00:00:00.000' and '2019-08-17 23:59:59.000' 
                               and CodigoSucursal ='A'
           )
```

Notas:

- Si solo tienes un `ID` para comparar, el `IN` es algo más cómodo, en caso de tener varios, la única solución es usar el `INNER JOIN`
- `tabla_donde_eliminar` es la tabla a la cual vas a eliminar filas, podría ser eventualmente la misma de la consulta (`TraspasosMercanciaSucursales`)
- El `DISTINCT` es opcional, pero útil si la consulta puede retornarte múltiples instancias de un mismo `ID`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio.... pude solucionarlo con esto .. te agradezco mucho tu ayuda!